# Conditional for MessageComposeResult in MFMessageComposeViewController with swift

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

I am attempting to implement the MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate's required method

```
 func messageComposeViewController(controller: MFMessageComposeViewController, didFinishWithResult result: MessageComposeResult) {
    }
```

The issue is that I can't figure out how to compare the MessageComposeResult with its associated constants in swift(MessageComposeResultCancelled, MessageComposeResultSent, MessageComposeResultFailed). So far I have tried:

```
result == MessageComposeResultCancelled
```

and

```
result == MessageComposeResult(0)
```

both of which return the error "'MessageComposeResult' is not convertible to MirrorDisposition". Any insight on how I can resolve this error would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think it should either be result == MessageComposeResult.MessageComposeResultCancelled or just result == .MessageComposeResultCancelled. I'm not 100% positive though because I'm not on my computer that has the XCode beta so I can't test it right now

Comment: thanks @sfeuerstein I had actually also tried both of those combinations but result == MessageComposeResult.MessageComposeResultCancelled states that MessageComposeResult does not have a member named MessageComposeResultCancelled. The second suggestion result == .MessageComposeResultCancelled states "Enum case pattern cannot match the values of non-enum type 'MessageComposeResult', I believe this is because the objective-c enum is converted to a struct in swift.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.MessageComposeResultCancelled` or the equivalents or, perhaps, `result.value == MessageComposeResultCancelled`

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I have already tried the first approach and I received the error "Enum case pattern cannot match the values of non-enum type 'MessageComposeResult'". The second approach also fails with error "'MessageComposeResult' does not have a member named 'value'"

Answer (score -1):

you are close but no cigar.

As a general rule of thumb, if the objC version is something like

`MessageComposeResultCancelled`

then the Swift equivalent is

`MessageComposeResult.Cancelled`

or in situations where the type `MessageComposeResult` is implied, you can just short hand it with

`.Cancelled`

**EDIT**

I was completely wrong about that `result == MessageComposeResultCancelled` worked for me.  I know you tried this already, so just double check that you have imported the MessageUI.framework into your project and make sure you `import MessageUI`.

Comment: thank you for your response but I am still getting the error "'MessageComposeResult.Type' does not have a member named 'Cancelled'"

Comment: I've double checked that the framework and messageUI are included, its still not working for me. I don't know if it helps but when I use that approach within a switch statement like `switch result{ case  MessageComposeResultCancelled:` I get "MessageComposerResult is not convertible to '_OptionalNilComparisonType'"