# xcode 6 beta 4 - MessageComposeResult is not convertible to OptionalNilComparisonType

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

I have just upgraded from Xcode 6 Beta 3 to Beta 4. In 3 my app was compiling perfectly however in 4 I have the following error. Can anyone explain and provide a solution please.

```
func messageComposeViewController(sendMsg: MFMessageComposeViewController, didFinishWithResult result: MessageComposeResult) {

    switch result {

    case MessageComposeResultSent :    //Error: MessageComposeResult is not convertible to _OptionalNilComparisonType
        label2.text = "Msg Sent"

    case MessageComposeResultCancelled : //Error: MessageComposeResult is not convertible to _OptionalNilComparisonType
        label2.text = "Msg Send Cancelled"

    case MessageComposeResultFailed :   //Error: MessageComposeResult is not convertible to _OptionalNilComparisonType
        label2.text = "Msg Send Failed"

    default:
        label2.text = "Msg Error"

    }

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    self.reloadInputViews()

}
```

Comment: Please provide where the MessageComposeResultSent is defined

Comment: @AlBlue: That is defined in the MessageUI framework, see https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/MessageComposeResult.

Comment: Already discussed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25020826/conditional-for-messagecomposeresult-in-mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller-with-swif Please don't duplicate.

Comment: @matt: It is indeed the same question. But none of the answers given there seem to work. Looks like a bug.

Comment: @MartinR That's my point. :)

Comment: @matt: I had not seen your edited answer. - Why don't you post that as an answer to the other question, and we close this as a duplicate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug in the way this module is bridged to Swift. Report it. To use the module, stay in Objective-C until the Swift bridging bug is fixed.

The main part of the bug as it stands seems to me to be:

- This should be an enum, and it isn't; it's a struct
- The struct has a `value`, which ought to be capable of comparison, but it has no getter (you can set it on initialization but you can't get it later)

Answer (score 22):

```
func messageComposeViewController(controller: MFMessageComposeViewController!, didFinishWithResult result: MessageComposeResult) {

    switch result.value {

    case MessageComposeResultSent.value :
        println("enviado")

    case MessageComposeResultCancelled.value :
        println("cancelado")

    case MessageComposeResultFailed.value :
        println("fallo")

    default:
        println("")

    }

}
```

Comment: Adding .value fixed my problem too.

Comment: In Swift 2, `result.value` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3):

For **Swift 2**, you will need to use `rawValue`:

```
// MARK: MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate

func messageComposeViewController(controller:MFMessageComposeViewController, didFinishWithResult result:MessageComposeResult) {
  controller.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion:nil)

  switch result.rawValue {

  case MessageComposeResultSent.rawValue:
    print("cancelado")

  case MessageComposeResultCancelled.rawValue :
    print("canceled...")

  case MessageComposeResultFailed.rawValue :
    print("fail...")

  default:
    print("default...")

  }
}
```

Of course, if you're just interested in one particular value, you could use an if statement as such:

```
if (result.rawValue ==  MessageComposeResultCancelled.rawValue) {
  // Message canceled.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For Swift 3.0, you will need this:

```
func messageComposeViewController(_ controller: MFMessageComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MessageComposeResult){

    switch result.rawValue {

    case MessageComposeResult.sent.rawValue:
        print("sent")
        break

    case MessageComposeResult.cancelled.rawValue:
        print("cancelled")
        break

    case MessageComposeResult.failed.rawValue:
        print("failed")
        break

    default:
        break
    }

    self.dismiss(animated: true) { () -> Void in

    }
}

@IBAction func sentSMSAction(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    if MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText() {
        let messageVC = MFMessageComposeViewController()

        messageVC.body = "My first custom SMS";
        messageVC.recipients = ["0123456789"]
        messageVC.messageComposeDelegate = self;

        self.present(messageVC, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }

}
```